# Calendar for ASP.NET MVC 3 website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, calendar, timeline

I have database with events and now need to show it by month on site.
Can you suggest any free components with customizable styles to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many projects available on codeproject for this purpose. The one i found more customizable is this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/360837/ASP-NET-MVC3-Create-a-custom-calendar-datepicker

another suggestion if you wanna make it AJAX based

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321268/DatePickerBasedEventCalendarMVC3andAJAX

another project which is latest

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404647/AJAX-Event-Calendar-Scheduler-for-ASP-NET-MVC-3-in

feel free to choose use whichever fits to your UX requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The following article shows you how to use an HTML 5 calendar with a jQuery UI datepicker as a fallback for un-supporting browsers.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1